# Is there a CMake '--install' switch?

Tags: cmake

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777817/what-is-the-cmake-install-time) there is a so-called 'install' phase in CMake. I'm used to run CMake in a sequence that looks like this:

```
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Is there a `cmake --install` command line switch meant to be invoked after this?

Although I figure it is somehow related, I'm not looking for the so called `install` command here (I perceive this to be a function rather than a command, but this is likely a terminology issue).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

No, this switch does not exist (until CMake 3.15, see my other answer).

If a project uses the `install` command, it generates the target `install`. You can call it with

```
cmake --build . --target install
```

This uses CMake's [Build Tool Mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html?highlight=cmake#build-tool-mode), which is an abstract interface for a couple of commands to the native build tool (e.g. make or Ninja) and can also be used to pass arbitrary arguments to the native build tool.

Comment: Somehow I find it a bit short though it does answer the question. Upvoting for now.

Comment: Or target `INSTALL` (upper case)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I checked for Linux and there is no `INSTALL`, only `install`

Comment: @PeterMortensen, it seems to me that the upper-case targets are Visual Studio specific. I can see it creates projects `INSTALL`, `ALL_BUILD`, and `ZERO_CHECK` along with other projects that look like what should be. Pity this was not normalized across generators or that CMake doesn't provide an extra layer to cover for it (much like it does with `--build`, `--target` and `--config`).

Comment: Principle of *most* astonishment for me: `make: *** No rule to make target \`install'.  Stop.`.

Comment: I would never have imagined a somewhat "modern" build tool would forget to support installation by default, and not as an optional extra task that may or may not be implemented depending on the will of the package author. At first look, that seems to be a *huge* usability regression!

Comment: @JohanBoulé You have to use CMake install command within your project. Not sure what your problem is, but if the user does not specify, what to install where, the target would be undefined.

Comment: @usr1234567 That doesn't make sense if it's not my project. Before CMake, we've had standard support for installation of *any* package that used, e.g. the autotools. I don't buy at all the argument that it has to be the way it is.

Comment: oddly enough, `cmake --install .` does not raise any errors on cmake < 3.15. It just assumes the current directory is a source directory. Just bit me on travis.

Answer (score 32):

Beginning with version 3.15, CMake offers an install switch. From the release notes:

> The "cmake(1)" command gained a new "--install" option. This may
> be used after building a project to run installation without using
> the generated build system or the native build tool.

Source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/release/3.15.html#id6

So you can use

```
cmake --install <dir> [--prefix <install-dir>]
```

The optional `--prefix` flag lets you override the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

Comment: it will display help for `install` command.
Use:
```
cmake --install <build_dir>
```
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project

Comment: @dimon4eg Thanks for the hint, I updated the answer accordingly.