# How to use CMake to install

Tags: cmake

I can build my projects successfully with CMake, but can I use it to install the results?

With `Make` I add the target `install` and call that from the command line. I cannot figure out if this is possible with CMake.

The final goal is to install a static library, dynamic library and corresponding header files in a platform-portable way. How I imagine it would work: On Linux, copy to `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`. On Windows it would probably be a user-provided folder with an include and lib folder.

The [install rule](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) suggests that something like this is possible. But how do I actually use it?

Currently I do the following:

1. mkdir build
2. cd build
3. cmake ..
4. cmake --build .

Here I would expect to do something like this:

5. cmake --install .

Comment: You can use `cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Debug`.

Comment: Yes! That does exactly what I was looking for. So simple, but I feel like everything about CMake is hidden in their documentation. Now that I know what I have to do I can instantly find a load of google and SO hits :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a cmake --install switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040522/is-there-a-cmake-install-switch)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the command `cmake --build . --target install --config Debug` for installation.

CMake's build tool mode supports further arguments that are of interest in this case.
You can select the target to build by `--target` option, the configuration to build by `--config` option, and pass arguments to the underlying build tool by means of the `--`  option. See the documentation (*[Build Tool Mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode)*) for the build-tool-mode.

In CMake 3.15 and newer, you can use the simpler `cmake --install` command to [Install a Project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project):

`cmake --install . --config Debug`

It additionally supports `--prefix`, `--component` and `--strip`.

Comment: Do you know if there is a list of all target options? The doc is not really clear about that. I've found clean and install until now.

Comment: @Art Stuurman There are all, clean, install targets and a separate target for every CMake target (every lib, every executable). See the documentation of the underlying build tool for further default targets. Or have a look into the generated Makefile.

Comment: @Art Stuurman Exactly. CMake is a build tool generator not a build tool itself.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd say that a build tool generator can generate a platform portable way to 'build', 'clean' and 'install'. Apparently all three exist, so I'm happy.

Comment: Is --install related here? Couldn't figure out how it fits with --build

Comment: @Jay `--install` option was added only recently in CMake 3.15. It adds some useful options like component wise installation and stripping the executables.

Comment: What's the best practice modern way to do a simple install then?

Comment: @vre comment regarding CMake 3.15 and `--install` worth adding to your general Answer. I end up here by searching how to perform component wise installation in a "modern" way.

Comment: @Jay If you know you have CMake 3.15 or newer, you better use: `cmake --install .` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project)

Comment: @Youw Perhaps you can provide a full answer?

Comment: how do you change the directory the files are installed in?

Comment: @ZackOfAllTrades Either by setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to the directory you want your files installed into when configuring your project or by using `--prefix` option of the CMake build command. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `install` command on your CMakeLists that will generate installation rules for your project. A basic example is shown bellow but check the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) if you need something more complex.

```
project (Test)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

install(TARGETS test DESTINATION bin)
```

Then after generate the makefiles you can ust type `sudo make install` and the test application will be installed on system bin folder.

Comment: note that `DESTINATION bin` is the [default](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-targets) for RUNTIME/executable dependencies, so you could just use `install(TARGETS test)` and it should end up in the same place