# Installing FreeRDP on Mac OS without using Homebrew or full XCode

Tags: macos, cmake, command-line-interface, freerdp

I'm trying to install [FreeRDP](https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/Developer/FreeRDP-Developer-Manual.markdown) on my Mac.  I have the pre-requisites installed and I want to do it without using homebrew or XCode (I do have CMake installed).  I've reviewed these instructions but I'm not sure what to do with them.

I run this:

```
cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

I get to this at the end of the process:

```
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/{username}/Desktop/package/FreeRDP
```

And when I try to run xfreerdp from the cli:

```
-bash: xfreerdp: command not found
```

It seems like I'm just missing the actual "install this on the OS..." part and can't figure out how with these tools.

I've been beating my head against the wall with this one and really hope someone has done it before or can point me in the correct direction. I'm very new to this type of installation but I'm excited to get it figured out.

Thanks in advance for any direction!

Comment: `cmake` invocation just **configures** the project. You still need to **build** it and **install**. Dependent on [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html), used when configure the project, you could use generator-specific way for perform building and installing. E.g. in case of `Unix Makefile` generator, `make` invocation builds the project and `make install` installs it. For *generator-agnostic* way of installing the project see the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428647/how-to-use-cmake-to-install).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks!  I'll try this direction!

Comment: I found that I just needed to add "--install ." which seemed to begin, then I reached what looks like a pre-requisite error:   ```CMake Error at winpr/libwinpr/cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "/Users/dwack/Desktop/package/FreeRDP/winpr/libwinpr/libwinpr3.3.0.0.dylib":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  winpr/cmake_install.cmake:77 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)```

Comment: You have **built** the project before installing it, haven't you? Building is performed with `cmake --build`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'll check this, even though this is likely the issue, but thank you for the assistance on this!

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm still unable to install after the build.  Here is my installation script:    cd ../FreeRDP
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ssl 
CMake .
CMake --build .
CMake --install .