# how to install xhtml2pdf in python 3.11

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf, python-3.11

i was using xhtml2pdf in django python 3.10 which was working well. now i upgraded my python version to 3.11. i tried to install pip intall xhtml2pdf, i get error

```
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************
```

I already updated pip, setuptools and installed pillow, wheel.i already installed microsoft visal c++ 2015. i am unable to install libxml2. I do not know where to find a currect file and how to install.  i am using windows 11 pro 64 Bit.

Please help me.

to install xhtml2pdf in python 3.11

[image: error message]

Comment: Please check how many python vesrions are installed in your machine

Comment: when i type python --version the output is python 3.11.0. and i checked in installed apps, i have ony one version which is 3.11.0

Comment: just uninstall this using command prompt and download newest version from python.org site and install it

Answer (score 0):

If go to github and look at about libxml2

https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2

you can find manual how to build it.
CMake (mainly for Windows)
Another option for compiling libxml is using CMake:

```
cmake -E tar xf libxml2-xxx.tar.gz
cmake -S libxml2-xxx -B libxml2-xxx-build [possible options]
cmake --build libxml2-xxx-build
cmake --install libxml2-xxx-build
```

https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/requirements.txt

Y'll see what other libs you need.

```
arabic-reshaper>=2.1.0
coverage>=5.3
html5lib>=1.1
Pillow>=8.1.1
PyPDF3>=1.0.5
python-bidi>=0.4.2
reportlab>=3.5.53
svglib>=1.2.1
pyHanko>=0.12.1
pyhanko-certvalidator>=0.19.5
```

then use

```
pip list
```

and inspect output.

Comment: ok. pip commands no problem, i can install from requirements.txt file. but i have type 4 cmake commands one by one in the terminal? where i can find tar.gz file?

Comment: where i can find tar.gz file? just download it from source (github). Look at green button called 'code'. Or download it through ssh\https

Comment: i downloded the zip file and extracted. should i go to libxml2-master folder and execute the cmake commande in the terminal?

Comment: sorry i don't use it  myself, but i think yes. after extract cd to extracted dir and execute:
cmake -S libxml2-xxx -B libxml2-xxx-build
cmake --build libxml2-xxx-build
cmake --install libxml2-xxx-build

where xxx is version of this lib

Comment: it might be helpful for u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428647/how-to-use-cmake-to-install

Comment: thanxs anyway. i tried but it  gives me lots of error. thanx firdaus

Comment: i found another solution. thank you verymuch.