# newbi: how to run a github project

Tags: linux, cmake

I try to run a programm called i210tool from github. [text](https://github.com/dgrafe/i210-tools/tree/master)

Downloaded it via git clone and in the director i run following commands:

`cmake -S . -B build cmake --build build cmake --build build -t i210-flash`

this worked fine and i can build the project:

`[ 50%] Built target libregmap-static [ 80%] Built target i210-static [100%] Built target i210-flash`

how can i run it on ubuntu? Guessing i need to install it but how?

tring to install it to run it with: `i210-flash --info --bdf 1:0.0`

Comment: Under the build directory, find the directory where executable `i210-flash` is created. Then you could run it via absolute path: `/path/to/i210-flash --info --bdf 1:0.0`. If you want to run the utility without the path, then add its directory to `PATH` environment variable, as usual.

Comment: "Guessing i need to install it but how?" - Normally, a CMake project could be installed by using `install` target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428647/how-to-use-cmake-to-install. But given project doesn't support installation: it lacks for `install()` commands in its `CMakeLists.txt`.